# Use DCMTK to read a JSON-formatted DICOM dataset

Tags: c++17, dicom, dcmtk

OFFIS DICOM Toolkit (DCMTK) offers functionality to convert a DICOM dataset to JSON (see below) but can the toolkit be used to read a JSON-formatted dataset somehow?

---

The C++ implementation can write a dataset in JSON format:

```
#include <dcmtk/dcmdata/dcdataset.h>
#include <dcmtk/dcmdata/dcjson.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    auto dataset = DcmDataset{};
    auto format = DcmJsonFormatPretty{};

    dataset.writeJson(std::cout, format);
    return 0;
}
```

But no method seems to be there for reading a JSON-formatted dataset.

The toolkit also ships with a utility called [`dcm2json`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dcm2json.1.html) that converts a DICOM file to the standard JSON-format; yet no utility for converting from JSON back to a DICOM file...

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such functionally in dcmtk. I'm only aware of that in Python and JS DICOM frameworks.

Comment: I think dcm4che also has a json2dcm command line tool that converts a JSON file to a DICOM file.

Comment: @KasperMarstal There is no fixed schedule. This tool is currently being developed by a new member of the DCMTK team. It will probably take a few weeks or even months before it is publicly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such tool or ready-to-use feature in the DCMTK, but there are plans to change this in the near future (i.e. this year).

Comment: Unfortunately, the discussion takes place internally (within the DCMTK team), but I've just created a "Feature Request" in DCMTK's issue tracker, so you could follow the progress: https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/issues/1116